# How to go about a long traverse with just Undercut holds?

Tags: safety, rock-climbing

I just recently got information about an easy climbing route. I am not sure about the grade though. The only part the worries me is a traverse, which is exposed. And long traverses have always been my weak point.
I have a couple months to prepare and practice. I plan to give it a try as soon as winter hits.

The traverse is full of all the Undercut-type holds.
How can I practice specifically for traverses?
How should I go about a traverse with Undercut holds specifically?

Comment: A downvote? Care to explain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How can I practice specifically for traverses?

A lot of climbing gyms (especially bouldering ones) have traversing walls. If you can find one of these practice there.

[image]

Or find a boulder that you can circuit climb (climb in a circle around the bottom).

[image]

> How should I go about a traverse with Undercut holds specifically?

Generally the trick to undercuts is to stand tall, therefore keeping your arms as straight as possible. This allows you to rest your biceps as much as you can and make's it easier to hold yourself against the wall. If the holds are above you then hang out away from the wall as much as you can, again you want to keep your arms as straight as possible.

Undercut's are all about the biceps. So work on this muscle to improve your undercut(ability)